# Using double precision in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to query a table using a `double precision` column but when I try

`select * from foo where bar > 2`

I got no results.

`select * from foo where bar < 2`

nothing too! When I try

`select bar from foo`

I can see all records there. Some values are like `1.31744579794415e-08`, `4.82082769315891e-08` and etc.

Already tried `bar < 2.0` and `bar < 2.0::float8`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: oops! I think here is not the best place. Can someone move this to DBA SE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solution work ?

```
select * from foo where round(bar::numeric, 2) < 2
```

But I am surprised since all those assertions are true :

```
select round(1.31744579794415e-08::numeric, 2) < 2 
select 1.31744579794415e-08::numeric < 2 
select 1.31744579794415e-08 < 2
```

Are you sure there is nothing else ?

Comment: Well, I'm using a too small number. Using this tool http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/scientific-notation-converter.php I discover 2 decimals is not enough to compare the numbers. In my example, `1.31744579794415e-08` actualy is `0.0000000131744579794415` and is very far from `2` in my query. I think I'll need `round(bar::numeric, 10)` to start to talk.

Comment: Without using your solution (the type cast) I have no results. I'm surprised too but once a wise monk said: `if it work then don't touch anymore`.

Comment: If a monk said so :-)

Comment: A long time ago he was a DBA.... Now he's counting llamas in Himalayas.