# Where clause with no result

Tags: sql, postgresql, precision, where-clause

I'm using an SQL query on a double precision column but I get no ressult.

```
select *
from chicago_2po_4pgr
where f_estimated=38867.0150708261
```

I'm sure that the row with `f_estimated=38867.0150708261`exists.

I tried to modify the query and use the solution mentionned in [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42232347/using-double-precision-in-query) but it works only if I change = to < or >.
I need to know the exact row with this value.

How can I get this row please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using double precision in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42232347/using-double-precision-in-query)

Comment: never use = with floating point. floating point is not an exact type.

Comment: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/ is good reading.

Comment: @Zephyr Thank you for commenting but it doesn't work, it works only when I change = to > or <.

Comment: @Jasen Thank you for commenting, I need to find the exact row that contains this data to manipulate it later.

Comment: listen to @jansen. It doesn't matter what you want if you're doing it wrong.

Comment: You can't compare floating point values for equality. It doesn't matter if you really want or need to - it simply cannot be done.

Comment: @nicomp I just clarify what I want. I clearly do it wrong (I didn't find any result) I'm just asking If there is a solution to get the exact row without using '='.

Comment: @KenWhite okey, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the constant is of type numeric -- which is precise -- but the column is a float.  These are likely to have some small differences.

One method is to convert them to the same type.  This *might* work:

```
select *
from chicago_2po_4pgr
where f_estimated = 38867.0150708261::double precision
```

However, that may not be generalizable.  A safer method is:

```
select *
from chicago_2po_4pgr
where abs(f_estimated - 38867.0150708261) < 0.0001
```

Or whatever a reasonable threshold is.

The safest method is to dispense with double precision entirely.  Represent the value as a numeric (first thought is something like `numeric(20, 10)`.  Then you can do exact comparisons.

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful and precise :D

Answer (score 0):

As the above comments mention, you cannot do a direct comparison with a floating point data type.

Instead, trying casting the `double precision` to a `numeric` type before doing the comparison:

```
select * from chicago_2po_4pgr
where cast(f_estimated::numeric)=38867.0150708261
```